# What anatomical structures do baleen whales use to vocalize?

Tags: zoology

What anatomical structures do baleen whales use to vocalize? How does this differ between species?

Comment: Look at there they don't give a definitive answer but it's already something https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Whale_vocalization (Baleen whales are called Mysticete whales)

Comment: They use larynx and folds in the larynx for underwater vocalizations. Source and details: https://www.sciencedirect.com/topics/biochemistry-genetics-and-molecular-biology/baleen-whale

Answer (score 1):

Discovery of Sound in the Sea (dosits.org) provides good general information on these topics.

According to DOSITs,
Marine mammals produce vocalizations using mechanisms similar those of land mammals. Pinnipeds (seals and sea lions) have a larynx similar to that of humans. Baleen whales also use a larynx to produce sounds. Toothed whales can produce sounds using their larynx as well as specialized air sacs near their blowhole. The larynx is used to produce whistles, while the air sacs are used to produce high frequency echolocation signals.
See https://dosits.org/animals/sound-production/how-do-marine-mammals-produce-sounds/ for more information and additional citations

Comment: The DOSITs website is a great resource with many links to scientific studies, but I believe they made an error in their description of toothed whale sound production. Toothed whales produce both echolocation clicks and communication whistles using the phonic lips in their nasal passages.

Answer (score 1):

Not much is known about the exact method of sound production in baleen whales and current knowledge is mostly based on dissections of dead animals.

Reidenberg and Laitman (2007) examined 6 baleen whale species (37 animals in total) and they identified a structure in the larynx, which they called the "U-fold"<sup>1</sup>. This U-fold is supported by cartilages and the shape and tension seem to be controlled by skeletal muscles, which might then control the sounds produced. Based on various features, Reidenberg and Laitman suggest that the U-fold is homolog to the laryngeal folds in other mammals. A key difference between the U-fold of baleen whales and the vocal folds of terrestrial mammals is that air flows in parallel with the U-fold, whereas airflow across the vocal folds is perpendicular in terrestrial mammals. Baleen whales also have a laryngeal air sac, which is homolog to the laryngeal ventricles of terrestrial mammals, which captures air as it is used during vocalisations, and allow air to be recycled back to the lungs in-between vocalisations<sup>1,2</sup>.

To my knowledge, there is no evidence that toothed whales produce any sound in the larynx. Toothed whales produce both echolocation clicks and so-called “whistles” by creating an airflow across phonic lips in their nasal passages, and the resulting tissue vibrations produce the sound, which is then guided into the water via a fatty organ called the melon<sup>3</sup>. Toothed whales have a pair of phonic lips in each nasal passage, and it seems that echolocation clicks are produced using the phonic lips in the right nasal passage and communication whistles are produced with the phonic lips in the left nasal passage<sup>4,5</sup>.

**References**:

1. Reidenberg, J. S., & Laitman, J. T. (**2007**). Discovery of a low frequency sound source in Mysticeti (baleen whales): anatomical establishment of a vocal fold homolog. The Anatomical Record: Advances in Integrative Anatomy and Evolutionary Biology: Advances in Integrative Anatomy and Evolutionary Biology, 290(6), 745-759. DOI: [10.1002/ar.20544](https://doi.org/10.1002/ar.20544).
2. Reidenberg, J. S., & Laitman, J. T. (**2018**). Anatomy of underwater sound production with a focus on ultrasonic vocalization in toothed whales including dolphins and porpoises. In Handbook of behavioral neuroscience (Vol. 25, pp. 509-519). Elsevier. DOI: [10.1016/B978-0-12-809600-0.00047-0](https://doi.org/10.1016/B978-0-12-809600-0.00047-0).
3. Madsen, P. T., Jensen, F. H., Carder, D., & Ridgway, S. (**2012**). Dolphin whistles: a functional misnomer revealed by heliox breathing. Biology letters, 8(2), 211-213. DOI: [10.1098/rsbl.2011.0701](https://doi.org/10.1098/rsbl.2011.0701).
4. Madsen, P. T., Wisniewska, D., & Beedholm, K. (2010). Single source sound production and dynamic beam formation in echolocating harbour porpoises (Phocoena phocoena). Journal of Experimental Biology, 213(18), 3105-3110. DOI: [10.1242/jeb.044420](https://doi.org/10.1242/jeb.044420).
5. Madsen, P. T., Lammers, M., Wisniewska, D., & Beedholm, K. (**2013**). Nasal sound production in echolocating delphinids (Tursiops truncatus and Pseudorca crassidens) is dynamic, but unilateral: clicking on the right side and whistling on the left side. Journal of experimental biology, 216(21), 4091-4102. DOI: [10.1242/jeb.091306](https://doi.org/10.1242/jeb.091306).